# Realtime API Listener for ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase

I have a Firebase API function which will be called every time when button is clicked. I used "axios" to get all the data in that API.

Is there a way or functions other than "axios" that I can use to have it realtime? 
I mean, there is a listener in the API that every time there is a change in the data, the API will automatically called.

I used to call this API for getting the data for my chart.

Thanks.

Comment: which firebase service you're using?

Comment: If you're asking if there is a realtime Cloud Functions API, no such thing exists.  HTTP requests don't work like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [server-side events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events). And as far as I know, Firebase does support those.

[check out this SO answer for a frontend implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42001592/8433471)