# Server Sent Event not sending without res.end()

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am writing a web application using Firebase for my client and Google Cloud Platform for my server.  I want to send updates from  the server to client using Server Side Events (SSE).

In client

```
eventReceived = (eventData) => {
    console.log(eventData)
}
|
   if (!'EventSource' in window) {
        throw 'No SSE support'
    }

    var source = new EventSource(serverURL + '/events', { withCredentials: true })
    source.onmessage = (event) => eventReceived(event.data)
```

In server

```
   res.set({
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive'
   });
   res.flushHeaders();

   res.write('retry: 10000\n\n')

   let count = 0;

    while (true) {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));

      res.write(`data: ${count}\n\n`)
      ////res.end()
    }
}
```

I get no response in the client unless I un-comment *////res.end()*, but this closes the connection.

I have tried various header options, such as no compression, but to no avail.

Any help will be GREATLY appreciated.
THANKS!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42001592/8016720

Comment: What server product are you using?  "Google Cloud Platform" is made up of many products.  Are you actually using Google Cloud Functions for your backend?

Comment: This is running as an App Engine.  My client is a Firebase app - https://lobyd-seller-client.web.app

The server is at https://lobyd-seller-server.wm.r.appspot.com/

Comment: @John Hanley - I will try that tonight.  Thanks!

Comment: @John Hanley - that link doesn't help me.  I have a server script that is issuing Server Sent Events to my client.  I am getting the messages, but only after sending res.end().
I have also tried res.flush(), but to no avail.